# How to upload file into different directory based on url token value

Tags: php

This is my code for html

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="L.CoursePage.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"     method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" /><br>
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="upasg">
    </form>
```

This is my php code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['upasg'])) {
        //folder to save in
        $targetPath = $id."/download/assignment";

        if (!is_dir($targetPath)){
         mkdir($targetPath);
         }
        $targetPath = $targetPath . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
        $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
        if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] < 2000) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$targetPath)){
                echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "The file is too big";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

What I'm trying to do is to upload file into different directory when the pageid is different.
For example:
in /L.CoursePage.php?id=1, the file I trying to upload in this page should be save in the 1/download/assignment path.

And I get this error:

Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\foundation\L.CoursePage.php on line 148

Warning: move_uploaded_file(TTT1234/download/assignment1.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\foundation\L.CoursePage.php on line 153

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'D:\xampp\tmp\phpBF13.tmp' to 'TTT1234/download/assignment1.txt' in D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\foundation\L.CoursePage.php on line 153
There was an error uploading the file, please try again.

Comment: You have a space in your file `input` name.

Comment: On line 150 `mkdir(targetPath)` I think you missed `$`

Comment: jereon & Mahasish Shome thank you both of u although I changed my code there are still some error

Answer (score 0):

The error says that PHP does not recognize targetPath, because you forget the `$` sign in `mkdir(targetPath);`

For the uploadedfile index, in your first code you say `name="uploaded file"` with a space.

These PHP errors are quite explicit :D

Comment: I have edit the code according to ur answer but there is still problem

Comment: can you try mkdir($targetPath, 0777, true);? It will create any nested directory in your $targetPath. I guess that the $id directory does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with construction of `$targetPath`. You set `$targetPath` to `$id."/download/assignment";`. And then you concatenate it with the name of the file:

```
$targetPath = $targetPath . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

But `$targetPath` doesn't have a trailing directory separator, so the concatenated string will look like `/download/assignmentfilename`. Use a directory separator:

```
$targetPath = $targetPath . '/' . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```